# Why doesn't su work in my app but works through adb?

Tags: android, root

I'm trying to silently install apps on my phone (rooted LineageOS, and yes, it's an internal use app made just for me).

I do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'pm install /data/user/0/MyAppName/cache/test.apk'")`, and it pops up the root warning, I give it permission, and `res.waitFor().toString()` returns 0.

But the app isn't installed.

However, when I run `pm install /data/user/0/MyAppName/cache/test.apk` in `adb root`, it's installed fine.

Is there something I'm missing?